# substituting other Javascript promise in chain on condition

Tags: javascript, promise, es6-promise, fetch-api

It's been a while since I worked with JavaScript promises, so I'm getting back up to speed with the latest features.

In a browser I'm downloading a file `foo.txt` from the server using the Fetch API:

```js
fetch("foo.txt").then(response => {
  if (!response.ok) {
    throw new Error(`HTTP error: ${response.status}`);
  }
  return response.arrayBuffer();
}).then(responseBuffer => {
  //TODO continue processing response
});
```

That works fine. But now I first want to alternately download `bar.txt` if `foo.txt` doesn't exist, and *then continue the same processing chain*. So I'm thinking something like this:

```js
fetch("foo.txt").then(response => {

  if(response.status == 404) {
    //TODO try to fetch `bar.txt`
  }
```

How would I `fetch("bar.txt")` and somehow substitute its promise result in the same chain, so that I could e.g. check its `response.ok` and continue processing with the existing promise chain?

Comment: Fetch bar.txt and return its response array buffer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do just that:

```
fetch("foo.txt").then(response => {
  if (response.status == 404) return fetch("bar.txt")
  else return response;
}).then(response => {
  if (!response.ok) throw new Error(`HTTP error: ${response.status}`);
  else return response.arrayBuffer();
}).then(responseBuffer => {
  //TODO continue processing response
});
```

It reads a bit easier with `async`/`await` though:

```
let response = await fetch("foo.txt");
if (response.status == 404) {
  response = await fetch("bar.txt")
}
if (!response.ok) throw new Error(`HTTP error: ${response.status}`);
const responseBuffer = await response.arrayBuffer();
//TODO continue processing response
```

Comment: Ah, so I can return either a bare response or a promise for a response, and they both get "unwrapped" into a response in the next `.then()` clause? (I'm starting to remember now.)

Comment: Yes. You can also `return Promise.resolve(response)` if you prefer cleanliness and make explicit use of `then`'s unwrapping behaviour.